# Is there a real sequence numbers $x_1,x_2,⋯,x_n$ that follows these properties

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Is there a real sequence numbers $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ that follows these four properties

1. there is a $49.5$% chance when you pick 5 of the elements of this sequence and you add them you get more than $n$
2. there is a $49.5$% chance when you pick 5 of the elements of this sequence and you add them you get less than $\frac{n}{2}$
3. there is a $1$% chance when you pick 5 of the elements of this sequence and you add them you get a number between $n$ and $\frac{n}{2}$
4. $x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_n=1000$

Comment: If we drop condition 4, this can certainly be done with $n=878$ (where $\frac{n\choose 5}{200}$ has only prime factors $\ll n$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen okay I think that will do what is the sum of $x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_{878}$?